# why cant i run all the test in android test project?

Tags: junit, android-testing

now ,i code android testing in the separate test project to test the application. i coded many test case and classes. now ,i want to write a testsuit. to run all the test.but it has a exception. the code is the follow:

```
 public static Test suit () {
        return new TestSuiteBuilder(AllTest.class)
                  .includeAllPackagesUnderHere()
                  .build();
    }
```

the exception is the follow:

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.netqin.myproject.test.alltest.AllTest
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)

what is the wrong,i cant find out the reason. any help is thankful.

Answer (score 0):

The method includeAllPackagesUnderHere() needs to be able to pull in tests from either the package in which your test suite is saved or any subpackages ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/suitebuilder/TestSuiteBuilder.html#includeAllPackagesUnderHere%28%29)).

So, you need to create a separate JUnit Test Case that actually contains your test methods in the same package. For example, you might have two files:

1) MyTestSuite.java

```
package com.example.app.tests;

import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder;

public class MyTestSuite extends TestSuite {

    /**
     * A test suite containing all tests
     */
    public static Test suit () {
        return new TestSuiteBuilder(MyTestSuite.class)
                  .includeAllPackagesUnderHere()
                  .build();
    }

}
```

NOTE: make sure the class within TestSuiteBuilder, in this case MyTestSuite.class, matches the name of the containing class, in this case MyTestSuite.

2) MyTestMethods.java

```
package com.example.app.tests;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

public class MyTestMethods extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<TheActivityThatYouAreTesting> {

    public MyTestMethods() {
        super("com.example.app",TheActivityThatYouAreTesting.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testFirstTest(){
        test code here
    }

    public void testSecondTest(){
        test code here
    }
}
```

In this case, testFirstTest() and testSecondTest() would be included in your test suite (MyTestSuite.class). Running MyTestSuite.java as an Android JUnit test will now run both of those tests.

Comment: Possible typo here. MyTestSuite must be "public static Test suite () {" instead of "public static Test suit () {" (suite vs suit).